# Can we interchange phrases " What's the date today?" and "what day is it today?"

Tags: grammar

Can we interchange the sentences " What's the date today?" and "what day is it today?"

In grammar is it correct to use these sentences interchangeably?

For example "What's the day today?" and "what date is it today?"

Comment: Up here in Quebec we say "What day/date are we?" ... not "is it".

Answer (score 16):

All of your sentences are correct, but may provide different answers.

> What's the date today and What date is it today?

are the exact same question, and will usually give the answer 'March 8th'.

While

> What's the day today and What day is it today?

are also the same question, but will usually give the answer 'Saturday'.

However, despite it being grammatically correct, I doubt you'd hear many people saying 'What's the day today?'

Comment: There's also the variants without the preliminary subject (complement): _What day/date is today?_

Answer (score 2):

What is the Date today would technically mean you were asking the number of the day, like October the 18th. But if you were to say "What is the Day today" would make you be asking the name of the day, like Sunday.