# Same day vs Same date

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct - same day last year or same date last year? Can we use same day/date instead?

e.g.: We went to the place the same day last year

Comment: [Can we interchange phrases “ What's the date today?” and “what day is it today?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156269/can-we-interchange-phrases-whats-the-date-today-and-what-day-is-it-today)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we interchange phrases " What's the date today?" and "what day is it today?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156269/can-we-interchange-phrases-whats-the-date-today-and-what-day-is-it-today)

Answer (score 5):

The two meanings are subtly different, I think.

"the same date last year" is clear enough, and unambiguous - you mean the 27th of June 2015 for example.

"the same **day** last year" could refer to a specific date, OR it could refer to the special status of a particular day, **which might not always be on the same date**:  for example, "Easter Monday" or "Martin Luther King Day" (an American holiday celebrated on the third monday in January, and therefore not a fixed date).

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'same date' if both visits took place on (for example) 3rd March.
I would however use 'same day' if I was referring to an anniversary of an event, which would be linked to a fixed date.
I would also use 'same day' if I had referred to the previous occurrence by something other than a date, such as 'the first Saturday of March'.

Answer (score -1):

i would say same date, as the day represents monday to sunday. Btw, you missed the conjunctions - we went to that place on the same date last year.